# Cygwin + /usr/bin/xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0

Tags: cygwin, startx

I am trying to run xcrysden on my windows PC using Cygwin. If i try to start an x server with : `startx`

A black window opens for a split second , and i can read the follwing information in the command line:

```
Welcome to the XWin X Server

Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project

Release: 1.19.2.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 HAL9000 2.8.0(0.309/5/3) 2017-04-01 20:47 x86_64

OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1 [Windows NT 6.1 build 7601] (Win64)

Package: version 1.19.2-1 built 2017-03-09

XWin was started with the following command line:

/usr/bin/X :0 -auth /home/admin/.serverauth.4688

(II) xorg.conf is not supported

(II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information

LoadPreferences: /home/admin/.XWinrc not found

LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc

LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...

winDetectSupportedEngines - RemoteSession: no

winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL

winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 00000005

winSetEngine - Using Shadow DirectDraw NonLocking

winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel

winWindowProc - WM_SIZE - new client area w: 1904 h: 1012

winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff

MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support

XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shar                                                                                                                                                                                               ed memory support in the kernel

(EE) AIGLX: No native OpenGL in modes with a root window

(II) IGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer

(II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast

(II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0

winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 952 506

(--) 16 mouse buttons found

(--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31

(--) Windows keyboard layout: "00000407" (00000407) "German", type 4

(--) Found matching XKB configuration "German (Germany)"

(--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "de" Variant = "none" Options = "none"

Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "de" Variant = "none" Options = "none"

winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.

winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0

OS maintains clipboard viewer chain: yes

winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.

xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down winClipboardProc - winClipboardFlushWindowsMes
                                                                                                                                                                                               sageQueue trapped WM_QUIT message, exiting main loop.

winClipboardProc - XDestroyWindow succeeded.

winDeinitMultiWindowWM - Noting shutdown in progress

(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Afterwards i get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0
```

If i type `xwin` to the command line a black window opens and stays open until i close it manually.

I really just want to run a few apllications that have no windows version. Unfortunately the solutions to seemingly similar problems i found on this site and other sources did not tell me much really, as i have limited experience with Linux and none with cygwin.

Comment: This sequence of messages is unreadable because the line breaks have been removed. Please edit your post, remove the part with quote formatting, and copy-paste the output again but this time use the code formatting tool (`{}` button or Ctrl+K).

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work. Now i manually enter a new line each time. I hope this is sufficient?

Comment: Sure - if you `startx` with nothing for your window manager to do (or no window manager at all), the X server will exit right away.

Comment: Dear Mr Dickey i appreciate your comment. Unfortunately i do not understand what you are trying to tell me as i have no experience with Linux at all. I just want to run one specific piece of software on my windows PC. Would you be willing to tell me what i need to do with a little more detail?

Comment: run `startxwin` https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html#using-starting